# Is there a way to dump Amazon MSK Topic to S3 directly?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I have planned to used Amazon MSK and i want to dump consumer logs to S3 . But i don't see any options. Do i need to write my own consumer or is there a way to consume Amazon MSK consumer output to s3 directly ?

Comment: MSK Connect might be the best option for your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka Connect is generally the best (easiest/scalable/portable/resilient) way to get data between Kafka and systems down (and up) stream such as S3. Learn more about [Kafka Connect here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-23&utm_term=rmoff-devx) and in [this talk here](http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect).

[MSK Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/features/msk-connect/) can run Kafka Connect workloads for your MSK on AWS.

Another option you have is to run your own Kafka Connect worker (which connects to MSK) and use the [S3 sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-23&utm_term=rmoff-devx) ([tutorial](https://rmoff.dev/kafka-s3-video)).

Comment: AWS has released MSK Connect recently (managed Apache Kafka Connect), so I've added it to the answer as an option.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a direct way to do it from MSK. You can use an external consumer to do it or preferably use [KafkaConnect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html) in an EC2 within the same VPC as MSK.

Either way you need to consider for high availability and data transfer costs. For HA, use consumers in different AZs. For costs, use [MSK 2.4.1](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-msk-adds-support-for-apache-kafka-version-2-4-1/) that allows consumers to fetch data from the closest replica.

Comment: What do you mean by using consumers in different AZs?  How does it translate into Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Amazon MSK now supports fully managed data delivery to Amazon S3 using Kinesis Data Firehose by Sep 27, 2023.

> Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose now integrates with Amazon MSK to offer a fully managed solution that simplifies the processing and delivery of streaming data from Amazon MSK Apache Kafka clusters into data lakes stored on Amazon S3. With just a few clicks, Amazon MSK customers can continuously load data from their desired Apache Kafka clusters to their Amazon S3 bucket, **eliminating the need to develop or run their own connector applications**.

and interestingly it also supports data transformation using lambda and output format as well Apache Parquet and Apache ORC

We utilized connectors previously, incurring significant costs. However, we are now transitioning to Kinesis as, based on our initial estimates, it appears to be a more cost-effective alternative to connectors.

[image]

[amazon-msk-data-s3-kinesis-data-firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/09/amazon-msk-data-s3-kinesis-data-firehose/)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-msk.html